# Where should I place external xslt file in java web app?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an external XSLT file that I'm placing in the /WEB-INF/classes/ folder. How should I use relative path to access the file?

```
File xsltfile = new File("xhtml2fo.xsl");
```

gives a `FileNotFoundException at D:\Softwares\eclipse\xhtml2fo.xsl`.

I'm runnning the webapp on a tomcat server.

Comment: Place it under WEB-INF/ and it will then be available as `servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/xhtml2fo.xml")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working directory in my tomcat launch configuration was D:/Softwares/eclipse and hence the relative path was being picked up from the same. It worked after I changed the working directory to ${workspace_loc:mywebapp/WebContent/WEB-INF} and file location as "classes/xhtml2fo.xsl"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ServletContext#getRealPath("/")](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the path to the `WebContent` root

Then Simply use this

```
String pathToFile = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + "/WEB-INF/classes/ folder/html2fo.xsl";
File file=new File(pathToFile);
```

Comment: I might have framed the question wrongly. Even with your solution I had "D:/Softwares/eclipse" appended in the beginning of the path. I have updated the answer.